# Animated series bases on human-operated robots fighting bad robots

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I want to know the name of this very old cartoon series of maybe Chinese, Japanese or Korean origin IDK. I used to watch it when I was a kid around 2005.

It consists of human operated robots who fight evil when needed, the pilots used to go inside the robots to operate them. These two evil girls and a guy used to bring a different evil robot every time.

This was also a funny and serious series. And I remember the name of one robot being "shasha".  Among the professional fighter robot there was this stupid robot and the kid.